# How to export multiple queries from DataGrip

Tags: postgresql, export-to-csv, batch-processing, datagrip

I have a file that contains multiple select queries.
I run these on a weekly basis to generate internal company reports

For example (these are not the actual queries):

```
-- Select number of users
SELECT count(id) from users;

-- Select number of active users
SELECT count(id) from users where active = true;

-- Select number of logins this week
SELECT count(id) from users where last_login > current_date - interval '1 week';

--- etc...
```

Is there a way, in DataGrip, to run all of these queries and export them to csv files?

I am able to run each query and then export the dataset, however, is a time consuming process doing this one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. Select all queries and then use `Execute To Files`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe there isn't a convenient way.

As a workaround, will combining all queries into one solve your problem?
It's not the most elegant way, but you'll get all the data displaying in a single result:

```sql
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users) AS "Number of users",
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE active = TRUE) as "Number of active users",
    (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE last_login > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '1 week') as "Number of logins this week"
```